# Is there any Equivalent of NOW() in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to migrate from MySQL to MongoDB and want to insert the current date as I do with `NOW()` in MySQL. Does anyone know a 1 line solution or should I do it with PHP?

Comment: Just insert current PHP date (google for php get current time)? Just speculating, have not used PHP, but the MongoDB driver should convert PHP date for MongoDB (and back).

Comment: It seems that it's the only solution.
MongoDB's driver doesn't offer the NOW() function.

Comment: How would that function be different from PHP date/time function? But I think you can get MongoDB to execute any javascript at server, if you want the server time (I don't know how exactly, docs should tell...).

Comment: I didn't say it's different but it's Mysql's own function, I can't use Javascript on the server I'm using PHP's MONGODB driver, and not SHELL/ Python scripts.

Comment: You can run javascript at server with the PHP driver, though you generally *should not* it seems. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11798227/1717300

Comment: @Sekai Checkout my http://stackoverflow.com/a/37061284/2911851 answer, it allows you to set the server's date to a field on insert time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Getting timestamp of document creation

If you are using MongoDB's [default ObjectIDs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) for your `_id` field, these include a timestamp component which you can use to infer the creation date for a document.  The PHP driver includes a [MongoId::getTimestamp()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoid.gettimestamp.php) method that can be used to extract the time from an ObjectID.

Note that the ObjectID is normally generated by the PHP driver (not the MongoDB server) so it is important to have your clocks in sync with `ntpd` or similar if timestamp accuracy is important.

#### Updating date/timestamps

In the upcoming MongoDB 2.6 release, a new `$currentDate` update modifier has been added which supports setting server-side dates and timestamps.  For more information see: [SERVER-10911](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10911) in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker.

Until this server-side support is available, your best approach for adding current date/time would be to set in your application code using `time()` or an equivalent function.

Comment: Awesome ! I just have to findout how to get the _id value and I think I read something about how to access to this value when inserting! 
Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 12):

For new features in `MongoDB 4.2`. You can use **[NOW](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.NOW)** to get the current datetime value.

> **Use Case:** to access the variable, prefix with `$$` and enclose in quotes.

```
db.students.updateOne( { _id: 3 }, [ { $set: { "test3": 98, modified: "$$NOW"} } ] )
```

Moreover, The **[CLUSTER_TIME](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.CLUSTER_TIME)** will return the current timestamp value but is only available on replica sets and sharded clusters.

Answer (score 5):

Have been looking into this for a long time, and found out this seems to work:

```
db.a.findAndModify({
  query: { _id: { $lt: 0 } },
  update: { $currentDate: { dateField: true } },
  upsert: true,
  new: true // optional
});
```

The idea behind the strange query part is that it always returns 'not found', so it always creates the document (`upsert: true`), but also, doesn't use that as value for the new inserted document (for example, using `{ _id: 0 }` in the query would actually insert a document with an _id field of value 0).

A similar approach can be taken using bulks:

```
var aBulk = db.a.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
aBulk
  .find({ _id: { $lt: 0 } })
  .upsert()
  .updateOne({
    $currentDate: { dateField: true }
  });
aBulk.execute();
```

Comment: Or use an ObjectId generated on the client side for `{_id: newId}` -- so the new doc will be created using this id.

Answer (score 2):

On an insert if you insert a BsonTimeStamp(0,0) in one of the first 2 fields the server will replace with the current timestamp on the server.

```
$ts = new MongoTimestamp(0, 0);
$document = array("_id" => 1, "s" => 1, "ts" => $ts);
$coll->insert($document);
$document = array("_id" => 2, "ts" => $ts, "s" => 2);
$coll->insert($document);
$document = array("ts" => $ts, "_id" => 3, "s" => 3);
$coll->insert($document);
```

Documents with _id 2 and 3 will have the current timestamp inserted into the ts field.

```
> db.timestamp.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "s" : 1, "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0) }
{ "_id" : 2, "ts" : Timestamp(1387236748, 1), "s" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 3, "ts" : Timestamp(1387236748, 2), "s" : 3 }
```

Also with the server 2.5.3 (to be released as 2.6) you have a new $currentDate update modified (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10911) that can be used to set a field to a date or timestamp

Comment: Since many drivers do not preserve the order of fields in an object, this approach can be tricky to rely on.  The positional timestamp behaviour is a side effect of historical internal implementation for replication, and as such may not work as expected in future versions of MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

To update the field with time you can use { $type: "timestamp" } or { $type: "date" } which explicitly specifies the type.

```html
db.collection.updateOne(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
      $currentDate: {
         lastModified: true,
         timestampField: { $type: "timestamp" }
      }
   }
)
```

timestampField is updated with the current timestamp, while lastModified is updated with the current date. The $type operator in this example specifies that the timestampField should be of the timestamp type

```html
// Update a single document with the current date and time
db.collection.updateOne(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $currentDate: { lastModified: true } }
)
```