# When inserting a document how to automatically grab the current systems date in MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

In a shell, I can do use new Date() as shown below:

```
db.myCollection.insertOne({
  ...
  "Last Modified Date": new Date()
});
```

How do I do it in MongoDB Compass? **new Date() is not valid**. <! Insert not permitted while document contains errors.>

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "xxxx"
  },
  ...
  "Last Modified Date": new Date()
}
```

I could manually enter the current systems date but I want it to grab that automatically when a document is inserted.

Thanks!

Tried below but no luck

- "Last Modified Date": new Date().toISOString(),
- "Last Modified Date": new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0] + ' ' + new Date().toISOString().split('T')[1].split('.')[0] + 'Z',
- "Last Modified Date": { "$currentDate": { "$type": "date" } },

Comment: Try this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204661/insert-field-with-currentdate-to-mongodb-collection-in-meteor

Comment: Thank you for directing me to that thread. It's unfortunate that using $currentDate isn't available when inserting a document using MongoDB Compass. I've just played with Studio 3T for MongoDB. The free version has IntelliShell module. The syntax that works in a regular shell works well in IntelliShell. Handy

Comment: Have you checked out [$$NOW](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/#aggregation-alternative-to--currentdate) variable?

Comment: maybe i missed something, but looks like NOW is for updating too. I normally use aggregators to output documents not to update/change the docs in the collection.