# Automatically include date field upon document insert

Tags: mongodb, collections

`MongoDB Server Community: v4.2.7`

Is it possible to define a collection where a date field will be included with every document insert?

Ie. if I insert `{ field1: "foo", field2: "bar" }`

I want a `created` field to be included: `{ field1: "foo", field2: "bar", created: Date(...) }`

Is this possible?

Edit: For more details, I want to do this so I can create a TTL index on the `created` field so documents are automatically pruned every x seconds. As I understand it, I need to manually insert the date field on each document insert. I would like to avoid this, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

As of now MongoDB doesn't support the auto creation of timestamps (besides the one which exists in the ObjectId) upon insertion. You'll need to save the document with the `created` field when creating the document.

You may find the thread [here helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782251/auto-populate-date-in-mongodb-on-insert)