# Insert date value from nodejs to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm using express with mongodb to insert some goods for a store website ..
is it possible to insert the current date of the inserting automatically without making any input for it

Comment: If you are using Mongoose then you can use timestamps https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps.

Comment: Is this what you looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782251/auto-populate-date-in-mongodb-on-insert

Comment: thank you for answering me i found what i need `let dateOfCreation = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/')` this gave me the date i want

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoose timestamp which is already been present in >4 version of mongoose
you can do it in this fashion

```
 var LoanSchema = new Schema({
  someField: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
  someOtherField: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
}, {
    timestamps: true
} );
```

It will automatically creates 2 additional fields in your collection as
createdAt and updatedAt

otherwise you can add default key to your field as like this

```
someDateField: { type: Date, default: Date.now()},
```