# MONGO DB - Get current Date and time in DD:MM:YYYY:HH:mm:ss without additional data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When I use `Date()`, it is giving me a string something like this - `Tue Mar 26 2024 11:28:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` But I want something in the format I specified. +530 in the end of that format is also acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for [`$dateToString`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any Equivalent of NOW() in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620368/is-there-any-equivalent-of-now-in-mongodb)