# Executing a raw Mongodb query in PHP. Is it possible?

Tags: php, mongodb

Is it possible to run a raw query (like the ones you write in Mongo shell) with PHP and its Mongodb driver? As an example, something like this:

```
$query = "db.foo.findOne()";
$result = $someMagicalObject->execute($query);
```

**Background:** Just to say, my knowledge about Mongodb is rather shallow and I do not know anything about *Wire Protocol* or the way that driver "speaks" to Mongodb. But, I was wondering if such queries are directly executable (for example, for making a tool like `phpmyadmin` / `adminer` for mongodb)? or we should somehow parse the queries and use the normal provided functions by the library?

I searched for some time and I have seen [Executing JS on MongoDB when inserting from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796546/executing-js-on-mongodb-when-inserting-from-php) and a couple of other questions. But I couldn't find any strong direct answer for my question.

Comment: The shell methods like `db.foo.findOne` are wrappers around javascript and C driver calls.  If you type the functions in the shell without parenthesis it will show you the source for the javascript ones.